# jquery contextMenu by swisnl add custom data to name depending on clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using [jQuery-contextMenu by swisnl](https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu) and I need to add some custom data to dropdown list depending on the item clicked. Consider the following html:

```
<div id="1" class="with-cool-menu"></div>
<div id="2" class="with-cool-menu"></div>
```

```js
$.contextMenu({
  //if add this callback, I am able to access props of clicked element 
  //callback: function(key, options) {
  //      var m = "clicked: " + key + " on " + $(this).text();
  //      window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m); 
  //  },
  // var id = $(this).attr('id');
  selector: ".with-cool-menu",
  items: {
    foo: {
      name: "Foo " + $(this).attr('id') // does not work
    },
    bar: {
      name: "Bar "
    }
  }
});
```

So I need to display in dropdown list id number of clicked element next to Foo, so if div id is 1, the name of the item in list should be Foo 1 (and if div id is 2, the name of the item in list should be Foo 2 respectively). Could not find relative example in docs. Any ideas how to do that? Thank you.

Comment: But I can access the props of the clicked element after clicking on some item in menu, like it is described in here => http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/on-dom-element.html (need to add a callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use de `build` callback (read the [doc](http://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#build))

This is the code:

```
$.contextMenu({
  selector: ".with-cool-menu",
  build: function(element, event) {
    return {
      callback: function () {},
      items: {
        foo: {
            name: "Foo " + $(element).attr('id')
        },
        bar: {
          name: "Bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ztznsq59/12/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [events.show](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/docs.html#events):

```js
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '.with-cool-menu',
    items: {
        foo: {
            name: "Foo"
        },
        bar: {
            name: "Bar "
        }
    },
    events: {
        show: function (options) {
            var fooItem = options.$menu.find('li')
              .filter(function(idx, ele) {
                 return ele.textContent.startsWith('Foo');
              });
            fooItem.text('Foo ' + this.attr('id'));
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.with-cool-menu {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.css">
<script src="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.ui.position.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/master/dist/jquery.contextMenu.min.js"></script>

<div id="1" class="with-cool-menu"></div>
<div id="2" class="with-cool-menu"></div>
```